# Possible ways of generating birthdate fields in a registration form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a website which requires user registration. The fields in user registration are the first and last name, gender, birthdate,location(country). Of these I am using select field or dropdown list for gender, birthdate and location. For gender its easy to code as there are only two options to be specified. For birthdate however I have day, month, year dropdown lists seperate for each. Also for countries I need a list of 200 countries atleast Then for populating values in these fields using normal programming  would be a dumb task. One option I have is using array and for loop for displaying the values. But the array would be too long and it would look unsmart in the code. I am using codeigniter for developing the website. What are the possible ways using codeigniter through which I can achieve this task with minimal and clean code?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish all of this client side with javascript.

Use a datepicker control for the birthdate fields. Go for something like [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) or even simply `<input type="date">`.

For the country list I would store it as an array as your said and I would hook it up with an autocomplete plugin. jQuery to the rescue again with [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 1):

For the Date field, I would suggest [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) or even a simple `<input type="date" />` will run on modern browsers but will be browser specific.

For the country list, I would suggest you get the official country list. search for `ISO 3166`. [Here](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm) is a link to speed things up for you. You can use the fields you like in a database or simple global array in PHP and then use a dropdown for the list.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

As Radu said, use jquery UI to accomplish the task for collecting the date of birth .

sample code :

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#dob" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                yearRange: '1905:2011',
                dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
                showAnim: 'drop',
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
        </script>


<td><?php echo form_label('Birthday', $dob['id']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_input($dob); ?></td>
        <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error($dob['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$dob['name']])?$errors[$dob['name']]:''; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

and for Country list, there are many publicly available database dumps , so I will use a databse to store the list of countries ..

**Adding some coolness :**

You can detect the user's country and display that as the default option and also with an option to select other countries from the dropdown .